# VBA For Loop not working as expected

Tags: vba

I was wondering if you guys can help me out. We recently moved from Outlook 2003 to 2010. We use an Outlook VBA script to take specific incoming email forms, read through them, extract out the information and compile it into a file.

The script works, but it only reads half of the messages in the folder. I did a count test on the folders, and that shows the correct number, but for some reason, the for loop i am using only executes on half of the items. So if there are 8 messages in the folder, then it only reads 4 of them, if there are 4 then it only reads 2, etc...

I cannot figure out what portion of my code is bombing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've posted only the for loop portion of my code. if you need the whole whole script, please let me know.

```
enter code here    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Outlook App Obj.
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 'MAPI Namespace
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("myemail@mydomain").Folders("TestAccMail") 'Outlook folder to access

For Each Item In myFolder.Items 'Loop through each mail item
    If (regex.Test(Item.Subject)) Then 'Test for TestAccX Message
        strDataSplit = Split(Item.Body, vbNewLine) 'Split the contents of the body to an array
        strOutput = ""
        For Each arrItem In strDataSplit 'Loop through the contents of the e-mail body
            If (regExData.Test(arrItem)) Then 'Test if line contains a field we need
                field = Split(arrItem, ":")(1) 'Store the value of the field
                strOutput = strOutput & Trim(Replace(field, Chr(160), "")) & "|" 'Concat the previous field value with current; seperated by |
            End If
        Next arrItem 'Next field in array

        If Not strOutput = "" Then 'Ensure the output var has data
            WriteToATextFile strOutput, file 'Append the data record to the provided file
            Item.Move myFolder.Folders("TestAcc Complete") 'Move mail item to completed folder
            recCount = recCount + 1
        Else 'If the string is blank, no data was extracted; Error!
            Item.Move myFolder.Folders("Errors") 'Move mail item to Error folder
            errCount = errCount + 1 'Incremeant error count
        End If
        messCount = messCount + 1 'Incremeant message count, error or not
    End If
Next 'Next TestAccX Message
```

Comment: Do you have a `on error resume next` preceding this? Is the for loop executing the correct number of times? If so have you added code to see if its the regex or strOutput that's causing the failure?

Comment: Alex - I'm using a "On Error GoTo outlookerror:", so if an error did occur, I would be notified about it. Also, the For Loop is only executing half the times it should. I put it in debug mode and Stepped through all the code. No errors occurred and the loop only executed half of the times it should have.

Comment: well, you wrote for each item in folder.items, and then you are moving the item to other folder, it is certainly a bad practice. For example, you are on first item, you move it. You will go to second item now, but since you have moved the first item, the second item gets the first index, but you have already moved on second index so it ignores the first item. Whenever you work on collection , always use a reverse loop so even if you move the item from collection, it doesn't change the index of the remaining items. Sorry if my language is unclear.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for information on how to properly loop through collections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Each loop: How to adjust code to move files in one run rather than multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252693/for-each-loop-how-to-adjust-code-to-move-files-in-one-run-rather-than-multiple)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how VBA handles collections but I'm guessing when you are moving items from the myFolder you are actually "hopping over" in the collection. Proper languages would not allow you to alter collection which is being processed by for each loop.

Comment: Janne - You're right! It seems that the "Item.Move myFolder.Folders.." portion of othe code is @ fault here. I commented it out and it read every message.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how I can replace this?

Comment: Use a `Do.While` loop instead